# Magnolia deployment on apache tomcat

Tags: maven, magnolia

I'm new to Magnolia CMS. I managed to put up an empty project via Magnolia CLI and created some light modules. I cannot find in the official documentation on how to deploy my project to online Tomcat server.

Is it enough just to copy magnoliaAuthor and magnoliaPublic folders manually to server or do I need to create a .war file? What is the proper way of doing this?

BR

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either upload war file or the expanded folder. It doesn't matter as war file gets expanded by Tomcat at anyway. [Here's some basic info on installing Magnolia](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Getting-started-with-Magnolia/Installing-Magnolia.html).
Alternatively, and since you tagged maven in the question, [here's docu on how to build custom webapp using archetypes](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Developing/Development-how-tos/How-to-use-Magnolia-Maven-archetypes.html).
And [here's link to documentation that explains you all about building custom webapp with maven](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Developing/Bundles-and-webapps/Creating-a-custom-webapp-with-Maven.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Magnolia CMS using Dockerfile. This is the  [Dockerfile](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/czimmermann/repos/workshop-bundle-reactor/browse/Dockerfile) that helped me out. Although I tweaked it a little.